# Can TestDisk or PhotoRec recover files by dates?

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

I just accidentally erased my home directory using the `rm` command. I am being pointed towards photorec and testdisk to recover the files. However, I have a backup, about 2 or 3 weeks old I think, and I was wondering if either photorec or testdisk are able to recover files by dates (last modification) since I am reading it may not be worth the trouble otherwise? It doesn't look like there is such an option on photorec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`photorec` can't recover files by date, but it does recover the metadata of a file if found with it (found it [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) in the section **recovery completed**). So after recovering all your data, sort your files by date to find the last ones.

In the link they said that `photorec` will recover the metadata **if found**. So he might not find them all.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm trying it. Using photorec, it asks me where to save the recovered files. However, it offers /home/djm and then ., .., desktop, etc. Since I am trying to recover my home directory, this is inconvenient. I bought  an external HD precisely for that purpose but it doesn't offer me to write the path for saving files. Any idea? I guess I could use desktop since I never wrote anything there but since they are on the same partition, it may still interfere no?

Comment: found it: just used the .. back to /media, then down again. Just started the recovery process. Thanks,

Comment: No problem. Good luck dude.